# Why Assets writes folder with 755 write permission

Tags: assets

I'm using assets 1.1.4 on a 2.5.3 EE install (Sorry but i cannot update now for any reason)
When I create a folder in assets this folder is written as apache:apache with this permissions:

drwxr-xr-x -> 755

is this right???

I ask this because this creates me big problems when i try to reconcile files using git.

thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not using a git pull as the apache user, so you're getting issues.

The 755 -- means only the apache user is allowed to write to that directory.

To fix it, either use sudo:

```
sudo -u apache git pull
```

or change the permissions to the correct owner and then reverting it back to apache

or change the permissions so everyone can write (777) and then reverting it back to 755.

Comment: Thanks Beverly everything you say is right but what I'm wondering is if I can change the behaviour of assets and maybe having it write directly with 777 permissions